# Using a gradle plugin before loading other plugins in the buildscript

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have my own gradle plugin that contains a file with versions for other plugins. Currently, whenever I make a new project, I have to copy them over as I can't use the versions from the plugin.

Is there anyway to load my plugin, apply it, and then load other plugins afterwards? Currently, I can only do this for the project myself when I make my plugin model named `buildSrc`, as it automatically adds it to other modules.

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "ca.allanwang:kau:$kau_version"
    }

    // Apply plugin before other dependencies so I can use it
    apply plugin: "ca.allanwang.kau"

    dependencies {
        classpath kauPlugin.android
        classpath kauPlugin.kotlin
        classpath kauPlugin.androidMaven
        classpath kauPlugin.playPublisher
        classpath kauPlugin.dexCount
        classpath kauPlugin.gitVersion
        classpath kauPlugin.spotless
    }

    wrapper.setDistributionType(Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL)
}
```

and how it looks like when I have the plugin as a module in my main project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    apply plugin: "ca.allanwang.kau"

    dependencies {
        classpath kauPlugin.android
        classpath kauPlugin.kotlin
        classpath kauPlugin.androidMaven
        classpath kauPlugin.playPublisher
        classpath kauPlugin.dexCount
        classpath kauPlugin.gitVersion
        classpath kauPlugin.spotless
    }

    wrapper.setDistributionType(Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by combining different things:

- Define your versions in a `Plugin<Settings>` that you apply in you `settings.gradle(.kts)` by leveraging the fact that the [`Settings` object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings) is `ExtensionAware`
- Define your plugin classpath in that same settings file [using `pluginManagement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management)
- Apply plugins in your projects, without specifying a version - see [this example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl) for a simpler version that does not define versions through `pluginManagement`

Example: https://github.com/ljacomet/setttings-plugin-props with the plugin in `buildSrc` but it could be published and used as a binary plugin without any problem.

Comment: Thanks! This looks to be exactly what I need. My current plugin is [here](https://github.com/AllanWang/KAU/blob/dev/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/ca/allanwang/kau/KauPlugin.groovy), and essentially adds extensions to a project plugin. Some of them are functions, though they don't change per project. Can they all be added to a plugin settings? If not, is it possible to have a single plugin containing multiple implementation classes?

Comment: `Settings` is `ExtensionAware` just like `Project`. Now you might need to split the extensions between settings and project depending on their use inside your build.

Comment: And please accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I'll accept the answer for now. I still have to test it to see if it works with both project and settings but you've shown me that I could apply plugins within settings which I didn't know before.